# Create a folder in Plone and set uid

Tags: plone, uid, plone-4.x

I have a Plone project which I need to fork; sadly, the UID of the `temp` folder (for Archetypes objects) is used in the code (as a module level variable, at least, not as strings all over the source tree).

When starting with a fresh ZODB - can I create the `temp` folder and set the UID? Or should I simply change that constant in the new development branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the uid for an AT object by...

```python
obj._setUID(uid)
```

The `_setUID` method is defined in [Products.Archetypes.Referencable Module](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/94cb35da36e2a33ce772b2437ae26d39b18e15cb/Products/Archetypes/Referenceable.py#L166)

For more information you can also check the [plone.app.transmogrifier uidupdater section](https://github.com/collective/plone.app.transmogrifier/blob/c21edde3c672268ca4db50dfe0db7e3d9b7d6a55/src/plone/app/transmogrifier/uidupdater.py#L58).